# icinga2 host state for passive host

Tags: icinga

I am using icinga2 for monitoring, and I want to include devices like NVR's located at customer sites. These cannot be pinged to check the host state.

The Icinga2 agent reports everything I need just fine without needing to forward certain ports.

However the host state itself is always 'DOWN' because this is checked using ping.
I would need the host to only be considered 'DOWN' if the agent hasn't reported anything in a timely manner.
For now I am checking on the HTTPS website that the NVR exposes, but that isn't exactly what I want since it could be possible that the NVR service is down but the device itself is up.

Comment: Why do you expect us to know what a "NVR" is?

Answer (score 1):

The default check set in `generic-host` is called `hostalive`, which will check if the host is pingable in any ways.

You would need to change the host state to a dummy check. Since Icinga2 always wants to know if the host is still alive.

Example:

```
template Host "non-pingable" {
  import "generic-host"

  check_command = "dummy"
  vars.dummy_state = 0
  vars.dummy_text = "Host can not be pinged, should be up, hopefully..."
}
```

This will run a very generic check, but setting your host state to UP.

You can also use any other check, like SSH, or a port test.

Comment: OK thanks, I am also looking into the distributed monitoring so that the one host that can be reached from the outside would ping the other hosts.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the cluster-zone connection check for that, verifying that the host's client is actually reachable and connected.

http://docs.icinga.org/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/chapter/icinga-template-library#itl-icinga-cluster-zone

Set vars.cluster_zone in your host object to the client's zone, and replace the host check command as well.